# How does one access a Range<Int> at a certain index?

Tags: swift, indexing, range

Let's say I have a `Range<Int>` called `myRange`:

```
let myRange = 1...10
```

How would I access the *0th* or say *5th* value in this `Range<Int>`?

I know that you can create an `Array<Int>` from the `Range<Int>` and access it with an index:

```
let rangeArray = Array(myRange)
print("myRange at index 1 has a value of \(rangeArray[1])")
//prints "myRange at index 1 has a value of 2"
```

But personally I don't find that very elegant.
Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to use the first or last index you can use the `startIndex` and `endIndex` properties.

You can use the following function to get the value at a particular index though.

```
func getValueOfRange(range : Range<Int>,atIndex index : Int) -> Int?
{
    if (index > (range.endIndex - range.startIndex)) || index < 0 {
        return nil
    }
    return range.startIndex + index - 1
}

let myRange2 = 6...10
getValueOfRange(myRange2, atIndex: 5) // Some 5

getValueOfRange(myRange2, atIndex: 11) // nil
```

Comment: Ah, there's a `startIndex` and `endIndex` property! That fixes my problem.
Thanks anyway!